# Unable to replace TraceWriter to ILogger in Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions, webhooks, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-api

I am working on SharePoint notification using webhooks and Azure functions. I have created an azure function and tried to follow [Using Azure Functions with SharePoint webhooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/sharepoint-webhooks-using-azure-functions).

But when I replaced the given

`public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)`

of azure function to the

`public static async Task<object> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)`

of the given reference. When I tried to run the csx file, i got the following error.

```
2020-02-04T11:56:51.572 [Warning] run.csx(8,62): warning CS0618: 'TraceWriter' is obsolete: 'Will be removed in an upcoming version. Use Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger instead.'
```

How can I get rid of this exception and how can I use azure function with ILogger parameter to get notification from SharePoint?

Comment: improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the warning, you'd need to not follow their example. That Sharepoint documentation is two years old. `ILogger` is the preferred method. You can use their example, but swap `Tracewriter` out for `ILogger`. They are mostly interchange-able and do the same thing. Write logs. It's not too hard. To do this, you need to do two things:

1. First, add a reference to the `Ilogger`.

   At the top of the function, add a `using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;` statement.
2. Second, you'll need to swap over and use the `Ilogger` method names.  For example, change `log.Info()` to `log.LogInformation()`

Here's [a full list of all the newer ILogger methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#extension-methods). When you dp get it working. Let the page owner know about the warning, and submit an update to the page with an `ILogger` example. Good luck!